# Extracting Memory Initialization File (MIF) from a BMP photo

Tags: java, c, intel-fpga, quartus, cyclone

I am working on the DE12-115 microprocessor from Altera using Quartus. In order to display a BMP image onto a monitor using the built-in VGA connections, I must first transform the BMP image into its MIF Format. The MIF format will be nothing but a lookup table that specifies the address of each pixel and the alias of each color using the RGB Color code. A Sample MIF File will have the following shape

```
DEPTH = 32;                   -- The size of data in bits
WIDTH = 8;                    -- The size of memory in words
ADDRESS_RADIX = HEX;          -- The radix for address values
DATA_RADIX = BIN;             -- The radix for data values
CONTENT                       -- start of (address : data pairs)
BEGIN

00 : 00000000;                -- memory address : data
01 : 00000001;
02 : 00000010;
03 : 00000011;
04 : 00000100;
05 : 00000101;
06 : 00000110;
07 : 00000111;
08 : 00001000;
09 : 00001001;
0A : 00001010;
0B : 00001011;
0C : 00001100;

END;
```

I haven't found any software that will enable me to transform my own images into the format above. However, I've found a C code that does it. Since I am not acquainted with C, I was wondering if anyone could help me understand the code, the library imports etc... so that I can transform it into JAVA. It would also be great if someone explains to me how to extract the MIF format from a photo and I could write my own code from scratch.
The C Code is below. Thank you all in advance

```
// PicTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//#ifndef LaserMaze_Bitmap_h
//#define LaserMaze_Bitmap_h


#pragma pack(2) // Add this

typedef struct
{
    unsigned short bfType;
    unsigned int   bfSize;
    unsigned short bfReserved1;
    unsigned short bfReserved2;
    unsigned int   bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER;

#pragma pack() // and this


#  define BF_TYPE 0x4D42             /* "MB" */

typedef struct                       /**** BMP file info structure ****/
{
    unsigned int   biSize;           /* Size of info header */
    int            biWidth;          /* Width of image */
    int            biHeight;         /* Height of image */
    unsigned short biPlanes;         /* Number of color planes */
    unsigned short biBitCount;       /* Number of bits per pixel */
    unsigned int   biCompression;    /* Type of compression to use */
    unsigned int   biSizeImage;      /* Size of image data */
    int            biXPelsPerMeter;  /* X pixels per meter */
    int            biYPelsPerMeter;  /* Y pixels per meter */
    unsigned int   biClrUsed;        /* Number of colors used */
    unsigned int   biClrImportant;   /* Number of important colors */

    unsigned int RedMask;       /* Mask identifying bits of red component */
    unsigned int GreenMask;     /* Mask identifying bits of green component */
    unsigned int BlueMask;      /* Mask identifying bits of blue component */
    unsigned int AlphaMask;     /* Mask identifying bits of alpha component */
    unsigned int CSType;        /* Color space type */
    long  RedX;          /* X coordinate of red endpoint */
    long  RedY;          /* Y coordinate of red endpoint */
    long  RedZ;          /* Z coordinate of red endpoint */
    long  GreenX;        /* X coordinate of green endpoint */
    long  GreenY;        /* Y coordinate of green endpoint */
    long  GreenZ;        /* Z coordinate of green endpoint */
    long  BlueX;         /* X coordinate of blue endpoint */
    long  BlueY;         /* Y coordinate of blue endpoint */
    long  BlueZ;         /* Z coordinate of blue endpoint */
    unsigned int GammaRed;      /* Gamma red coordinate scale value */
    unsigned int GammaGreen;    /* Gamma green coordinate scale value */
    unsigned int GammaBlue;     /* Gamma blue coordinate scale value */
} BITMAPINFOHEADER;

/*
 * Constants for the biCompression field...
 */

#  define BI_RGB       0             /* No compression - straight BGR data */
#  define BI_RLE8      1             /* 8-bit run-length compression */
#  define BI_RLE4      2             /* 4-bit run-length compression */
#  define BI_BITFIELDS 3             /* RGB bitmap with RGB masks */

typedef struct                       /**** Colormap entry structure ****/
{
    unsigned char  rgbBlue;          /* Blue value */
    unsigned char  rgbGreen;         /* Green value */
    unsigned char  rgbRed;           /* Red value */
    unsigned char  rgbReserved;      /* Reserved */
} RGBQUAD;


unsigned char *LoadBitmapFile(char *filename, BITMAPINFOHEADER *bitmapInfoHeader)
{
    FILE *filePtr; //our file pointer
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bitmapFileHeader; //our bitmap file header
    unsigned char *bitmapImage;  //store image data int imageIdx=0;  //image index counter
    unsigned char tempRGB;  //our swap variable

    //open filename in read binary mode
    filePtr = fopen(filename,"rb");
    if (filePtr == NULL)
        return NULL;

    //read the bitmap file header
    fread(&bitmapFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,filePtr);

    //verify that this is a bmp file by check bitmap id
    if (bitmapFileHeader.bfType !=0x4D42)
    {
        fclose(filePtr);
        return NULL;
    }

    //read the bitmap info header
    fread(bitmapInfoHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,filePtr);

    //move file point to the begging of bitmap data
    fseek(filePtr, bitmapFileHeader.bfOffBits, SEEK_SET);

    //allocate enough memory for the bitmap image data
    bitmapImage = (unsigned char*)malloc(bitmapInfoHeader->biSizeImage);

    //verify memory allocation
    if (!bitmapImage)
    {
        free(bitmapImage);
        fclose(filePtr);
        return NULL;
    }

    //read in the bitmap image data
    fread(bitmapImage,bitmapInfoHeader->biSizeImage,1,filePtr);

    //make sure bitmap image data was read
    if (bitmapImage == NULL)
    {
        fclose(filePtr);
        return NULL;
    }

    //swap the r and b values to get RGB (bitmap is BGR)
    /*for (imageIdx = 0,imageIdx < bitmapInfoHeader->biSizeImage;imageIdx+=3)
    {
        tempRGB = bitmapImage[imageIdx];
        bitmapImage[imageIdx] = bitmapImage[imageIdx + 2];
        bitmapImage[imageIdx + 2] = tempRGB;
    }*/
    //close file and return bitmap iamge data
    fclose(filePtr);
    return bitmapImage;
}
double round(double d)
{
  return floor(d + 0.5);
}


bool generateMIF(unsigned char *bitmapData, long tSize, char *file)
{
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen (file,"w");
    if (pFile==NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to Open file to write \n");
        return 0;
    }
    char buff[40];
    sprintf(buff,"DEPTH = %d;\n",tSize/3);
    fputs("WIDTH = 8;\n",pFile);
    fputs(buff,pFile);
    fputs("ADDRESS_RADIX = HEX;\n",pFile);
    fputs("DATA_RADIX = HEX;\n",pFile);
    fputs("CONTENT BEGIN\n",pFile);
    long ind=0;
    long addr=0;
    for (ind=tSize-1;ind>=0; ind-=3)
    {

        unsigned char R=round(bitmapData[ind]/255.0*7.0);
        unsigned char G=round(bitmapData[ind-1]/255.0*7.0);
        unsigned char B=round(bitmapData[ind-2]/255.0*3.0);

        unsigned char Var = R *32 + G *4 + B;

        sprintf(buff,"%X : %X ;\n",addr,Var);
        fputs(buff,pFile);
        addr++;
    }
    fputs("END;\n",pFile);
    fclose (pFile);

}


bool generateLUTMIF(char *file)
{
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen (file,"w");
    if (pFile==NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to Open file to write \n");
        return 0;
    }
    char buff[40];
    fputs("WIDTH = 24;\n",pFile);
    fputs("DEPTH = 256;\n",pFile);
    fputs("ADDRESS_RADIX = HEX;\n",pFile);
    fputs("DATA_RADIX = HEX;\n",pFile);
    fputs("CONTENT BEGIN\n",pFile);
    long ind=0;
    long addr=0;
    for (ind=0;ind<256; ind++)
    {
        unsigned char C=ind;
        unsigned char R=C >> 5;
        R = R* 255/7;
        unsigned char G= (C >> 2)&0x07;
        G= G* 255 / 7;

        unsigned char B=C & 0x3;
        B=B*255/3;


        sprintf(buff,"%X : %02X%02X%02X ;\n",ind,R,G,B);
        fputs(buff,pFile);
        addr++;
    }
    fputs("END;\n",pFile);
    fclose (pFile);

}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("Reading Image... \n");
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bitmapInfoHeader;

    unsigned char *bitmapData;
    bitmapData = LoadBitmapFile("d:\\back_24.bmp",&bitmapInfoHeader);
    long tSize= bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight *bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * 3 ;//24 bps 
    generateMIF(bitmapData,tSize,"D:\\backMIF.txt");
    generateLUTMIF("D:\\lutMIF.mif");
    printf("Done !");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gimp has an option to output a file as a 'C' structure.  You can remove the header and use only the data.  It should also work in Java.  The primary issue is to read and parse the BMP to get the array data.  It should be easy to create the MIF format in any language, given the array.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use Matlab. It will become so easy.
If yo use c, you should define some struct, try to jump the header of a picture. that is meaningless. But if you use Matlab, you cam just open the picture and get the data! 
This is my Matlab Code, Hope to help you:

```
  %mcode to create a mif file
    src = imread('lena.jpg');
    gray = rgb2gray(src);
    [m,n] = size( gray ); %size od your picture

    N = m*n; %your ram or rom depth。
    word_len = 8; 
    data = reshape(gray, 1, N);% reshape you picture's data

    fid=fopen('gray_image.mif', 'w'); % open mif file 
    fprintf(fid, 'DEPTH=%d;\n', N);
    fprintf(fid, 'WIDTH=%d;\n', word_len);

    fprintf(fid, 'ADDRESS_RADIX = UNS;\n'); 
    fprintf(fid, 'DATA_RADIX = HEX;\n'); 
    fprintf(fid, 'CONTENT\t');
    fprintf(fid, 'BEGIN\n');
    for i = 0 : N-1
    fprintf(fid, '\t%d\t:\t%x;\n',i, data(i+1));
    end
    fprintf(fid, 'END;\n'); % prinf the end
    fclose(fid); % close your file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I'm not familiar with matlab, would you mind telling me how exactly I could compile the code in it and add a picture? Thanks a bunch buddy!

Comment: @dou2abou If you  use Matlab, You need not to complile the code. just open the code in matlab, then put your picture into the path where the code is. and click the 'run' button. of course you shuold change the file name.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a project about configuring an Altera FPGA to a monitor, so I needed a MIF file generator. I saw there are not a lot online, and some do not even compile.

So I decided to write my own in Java, it works and handles almost all possible errors. The tool, however, will first convert the image to grayscale, and only then will the MIF file be created.

You can find my tool on my page on [GitHub](https://github.com/esposem/MifGenerator).